# Multiple files data sharing

Tags: c++, vector, struct, header

data.h    http://pastebin.com/5mLVqEa3
main.cpp  http://pastebin.com/NGYbGuuT

I'm trying to make a separate file to hold data so that my code looks nicer and is more easily managed and read. There's the code, when I compile it, it displays error "anes11 does not name a type" then for bnes11 and all of them for every line where I entered data (lines 25, 26, 27, 30, 31, 32.. etc). When I move the data to main.cpp into int main() it compiles just fine and outputs anes11.ime. When I put put the area where I enter the data (lines 25-27) in curly brackets then I get error "Unqualified identifier before {" or something along those lines.

Comment: If you put that code in the file "main.cpp" but outside of the body of `main` you will get the same errors. You can only have declarations and definitions in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do any *statement* in the global scope (outside any function), you can only do *initialization*.

So I recommend you create *constructors* for your structures, and do initialization in them.

So instead of e.g.

```
extern Ucenik anes11;
anes11.ime="Anes11";
anes11.prezime="Sprecic";
anes11.ocjene.push_back(4);anes11.ocjene.push_back(2);anes11.ocjene.push_back(3);
```

You have, in your header file the declaration

```
extern Ucenik anes11;
```

then in *one* source file (simple now when you have only a single source file in your project, crucial when you start working with multiple source files):

```
Ucenik anes11("Anes11", "Sprecic", 4, 2, 3);
```

Then you can define the structure, with constructor, like

```
struct Ucenik{
    string ime;
    string prezime;
    vector<int> ocjene;

    // Constructor
    Ucenik(const std::string& i, const std::string& p,
           const int i1, const int i2, const int i3)
        : ime{i}, prezime{p}, ocjene{i1, i2, i3}
    { }
};
```